# Is there a shared Form.ShowDialog method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a new developer that is calling Showdialog (in VB.NET) on a Windows Forms form without first creating an instance of the form.

How is this possible? I don't see a shared method for ShowDialog...

I'm not crazy about this approach either as it seems to me that the dialog will not be disposed until the application exits.

What am I missing? Is this a new best practice?

OK, Form2 is just a blank form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please show some code. There is no shared / static `ShowDialog` method.

Comment: Yes, so i thought. However, if you simple define a new form, it's possible to then call ShowDialog on the the class without first instantiating the form. This is in vb.net in vs 2008.

Comment: As I said before, please show some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a VB.NET "feature". VB.NET creates default instances for Forms, that you can use directly without creating an instance explicitly. So in this code, `Form2.ShowDialog` refers to the `ShowDialog` method on the default instance, not a static (Shared) method. Yes, it's ugly...